# Using REST API to create a Rally user in .NET

Tags: .net, rally

I want to create a new Rally user with the following C# code

```
DynamicJsonObject newUser = new DynamicJsonObject();
newUser["FirstName"] = "Joe";
newUser["LastName"] = "Developer";
newUser["UserName"] = "joejoe@joejoe.com";
newUser["DisplayName"] = "The developer";
CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create("User", newUser);
```

But it fails all the time, anyone has an idea?

Comment: If it fails, it must have an error message that tells you something relevant about the issue. Can you add the message here?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that it has the error message attached
I did not provide the EmailAddress field, that's why

    newUser["EmailAddress"] = "joejoe@joejoe.com";

Thanks MilkyWayJoe for reminding me that

Comment: HuyNA could you post that as an answer to your own question? There will be a time lag before you can accept your own answer, but it helps to have solid "accepted" answers for the tag forum.

Comment: just did, thanks Mark for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MilkyWayJoe for reminding me to look at the attached error message

It turns out that "EmailAddress" is required, although it might be similar to "UserName" field above

```
newUser["EmailAddress"] = "joejoe@joejoe.com"
```

This solves the problem